# Change branch of GIT GUI

Tags: git

I was working with git and I don't know how this happened but by default I am seeing this as my master branch "GIT Gui (C:/) C/" Can you help me in removing it to something else like 
C:/MyTestFolder .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After this guide on "[Getting started with git gui on Windows](http://matthew-brett.github.com/pydagogue/git_gui_windows.html)":

[image: git gui]

The only way it could indicate another directory than `C:/MyTestFolder` is if your `.git` had somehow moved to `C:/`

[image: dot git folder]

So I would first check where that `.git` directory is right now.