# Using git gui with multiple .git repositories?

Tags: git, user-interface, github, repository

I need to change the default git  repository of the git gui.  I know that the  default is the one closest to the  C drive, but I need to access one somewhere else in my local drive.

How  do I access a different local git repository?

This is  a similar question: [Change branch of GIT GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637225/change-branch-of-git-gui)

But I have multiple git  repositories, and they are in various  places in my  local drive.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into git bash and navigate to the directory that your  git repository  is in.  Then  launch git gui using the  following command:

```
start git gui
```